# How to get size of array nested in another array with mongoose aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have document in my collection

```
{
  _id: "8sd7f8s7df8s7df8"
  projects: [
    {
      name: inbox,
      tasks: [
        { name: 'task1' }
        { name: 'task2' }
        { name: 'task3' }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find document by `_id` and get number of `tasks` inside each `project`

I wrote this `aggregate` code but it's getting me number of `tasks` across all `projects` rather then size of each `tasks` array

```
User.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}},
  { $project: {
    _id: 0,
    'projects.name': 1,
    'projects.count': { $size: '$projects.tasks' }
  }}
])
```

How I should change this to get correct value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing an **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** first before the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline:

```
User.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": userId } },
    { "$unwind": "$projects" },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "projects.name": 1,
            "projects.count": { "$size": "$projects.tasks" }
        }
    }
]).exec(callback);
```

Comment: Thanks @chridam, that helps.